# Mithril - Select options getting re-sorted when selection is made

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

(Using Mithril 0.2.4)

I have a select element with several options in it. Sometimes, when an item is selected, the order of the choices in the dropdown gets changed, re-sorted in a seemingly random way. I haven't seen this with other Mithril select elements, but the values in this one are integers, and I suspect that is the trigger somehow.

Here is the code generating the element

```
m('label[for=min_reach]', 'Minimum Reach')
m('select[name=min_reach]',{value: ctrl.minReach, onchange: () -> ctrl.minReach = @value; ctrl.updateStuff()}, [
  selectedReach = (key) -> 
    if ctrl.minReach == key then "[selected=selected]" else ''
  m('option[value=0]' + selectedReach('0'), '0')
  m('option[value=1000]' + selectedReach('1000'), '1,000')
  m('option[value=5000]' + selectedReach('5000'), '5,000')
  m('option[value=10000]' + selectedReach('10000'), '10,000')
  m('option[value=50000]' + selectedReach('50000'), '50,000')
  m('option[value=100000]' + selectedReach('100000'), '100,000')
  m('option[value=250000]' + selectedReach('250000'), '250,000')
  m('option[value=1000000]' + selectedReach('1000000'), '1,000,000')
])
```

On initial page load, the options in the dropdown are order as expected (order shown above). But after selecting 50,000 for example, it now looks like:

[image: auto-sorted options]

If I continue to select options, the sort keeps changing.  My goal here is to keep the dropdown options in the same order as shown in the code above.

Comment: Maybe adding a key to the option will help? http://mithril.js.org/keys.html (new docs, but the concept applies to the 0.x branch too)

Comment: My Livescript isn't too hot, but I was unable to replicate this using Javascript: https://jsbin.com/goxexop/edit?js,output – maybe some external code is modifying the structure?

Comment: @ciscoheat I did try adding keys, without success....

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```js
const ctrl = {
  minReach: 50000,
  updateStuff: () => { console.log('value selected: ' + ctrl.minReach)},
  opts: [0, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 250000, 1000000]
}

const App = {
  view: () => [
    m('label[for=min_reach]', 'Minimum Reach'),
    m('select[name=min_reach]', {
      value: ctrl.minReach,
      onchange: e => {
        ctrl.minReach = ctrl.opts[e.target.selectedIndex]
        ctrl.updateStuff()
      }
    }, [
      ctrl.opts.map(o => m('option', { value: o }, o.toLocaleString()))
    ])
  ]
}

m.mount(document.getElementById('app'), App)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/1.1.6/mithril.js" type="module"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I agree with Ty's answer. You are missing `value` and `onchange` in your code. I also like the fact that all data are in `const` particularly good practice to do. ctrl.updateStuff() can be an external function and it does not have to be tired to ctrl...